# How to create a transparent sunburst overlay?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, layers, overlay

I need a sunburst to be continuous throughout my composition, but with different colours in different areas.

[Denver County Fair Poster](http://www.denvercountyfair.org/storage/DCF_2013_POSTER_th.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1361746515630)

In this poster the sunburst is in the background and extends outside the frame with different colours and gradients.

Also, what would you call this kind of frame?

Comment: Hi Christine, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: "The same sunburst" extends beyond the inner frame? How could you tell?

Comment: Hi @AndrewH, I actually hadn't tried anything yet, just had an idea that it could be done using several separate layers, and wondered if it could be done to create a semi-transparent sunburst that was between the background colour layers and the forefront image layers. My question is if it is possible, and suggestions on how best to accomplish the effect.

Comment: @Jongware, I don't know if they are the same layer, they just line up - I suppose I should say that it appears (visually) that they are, and again, is this possible to accomplish with a single layer and opacity?

Comment: It does not have to be transparent just recolorisation of same pattern with different masking that's all.

Comment: You image 404s for me, could you please post another link? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't see the attached example but a little image-Googling made me guess it's the 2013 Denver County Fair poster. If it is, that effect can be done in Inkscape. Here's one way to do it:

1. Make 2 different gradient filled "rays" per sunburst. The angle of the pennant shapes depends on how many rays of each you want in a sunburst (9 degrees in this case, with 20 of each kind of ray per sunburst).

   First, move a pennant's center of rotation to its tip twice until the rotate and skew controls appear, move the cross rotation point that also appears to the pointy tip [snap to cusp nodes to make this easier]).

[image: Move rotation point]

2. Use the transform tool (Shift+Ctrl+M) for duplicating and rotating the cloned pennants to make a sunburst. Group the rays once a sunburst is complete. You need a yellow and a red sunburst

[image: duplicate and rotate rays]

3. Clip the sunburst by placing your desired shape (rectangle in this case) on top of the sunburst, right clicking on them, and selecting "Set clip".

[image: Clip sunburst]

The yellow sunburst clip group below is more fancy. It has a white background shape on the bottom to prevent the red sunburst from showing through and muddying the colors), a dark green "mountain" shape above it, and the yellow sunburst (made slightly transparent) on top -- all grouped together before clipping with the "inner frame" rectangle.
[image: Clip sunbursts]

You can also tweak the gradient of the original rays to have effects like this:
[image: Tweak ray gradients for cool effects]